# PHP selectively remove and leave markup

Tags: php, wordpress, strip-tags

I am using wordpress custom fields to dynamically display a imdb link to an actors name on multiple pages of the site. In one section, I want to remove the link markup (a href) leaving just the actors name. I tried using php strip_tags which worked great, however it also removed the break in between actors names. I want it JUST to remove the link market and leave the `<br>` markup. See current markup:

```
<?php $response = get_field('director'); ?>
<span id="dir"><?php echo strip_tags($response); ?></span>
```

How would I use php to leave the breaks but remove the link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the allowed tags:

```
strip_tags($response, '<br>');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can specify allowable tags as the second parameter of the strip_tags function.

```
string strip_tags ( string $str [, string $allowable_tags ] )
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `preg_replace` to do that

strip_tags is fine if you only need to keep "br"